# How do you save a dynamically generated element to your database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, database

Let's say you use the Embedly API and make the call in your application.js file:

```
$('a.oembed').embedly({maxWidth:300,'method':'replace'}).bind('embedly-oembed', function(e, oembed){ 
           alert(oembed.title);
});
```

Now you have the hash `oembed` and can call, for example, `ombed.thumbnail_url` or `oembed.title` in the callback function. I want to know how you would save one of these elements in the call back function to your database.

Would the jQuery code look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   data: { title: 'oembed.title', thumbnail_url: 'oembed.thumbnail_url'}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to post the title and thumbnail_url back to your application using AJAX - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming).

The jQuery ajax api is very straightforward - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Comment: I'm actually fairly new to jQuery. I posted above what I think the jQuery code might look like. Is this right? i'm not sure if I need a `url:` setting in there.

Comment: That's right. You do need an url setting - pointed to the url that handles creating the embed resource on your server.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure which url that is. Currently the dynamic content is generated by my application.js file, but that's where I'm going to be calling .ajax() anyway. Should I be setting url to `application.js`?

Comment: No. You need to have a server, backed by a database, that provides you with a url where you can post your data. What is your server stack?

Comment: As of now I'm just using the built in rails server for development.

Comment: and the sqlite db that comes with rails too

Comment: Setting up a resource in rails is really easy. From the command line type './script/generate resource Embed title:string thumbnail_url:string'  If you do this, then you will be able to point your ajax call at /embeds.

Comment: Oh, does that create a model and controller? Because right now I just have title as a database column in my videos table.

Comment: Could I just point the ajax call at my videos resource at `/videos`?

Comment: Yes, the resource generator does create a model and controller. It sounds like you probably can point the ajax call at /videos.

Comment: yeah /videos is the index controller, but what about the show controller?

Comment: The controller is probably the same - VideosController. The urls that map to the different actions are: GET /videos (list), GET /videos/ID (show), POST /videos (create), PUT /videos/ID (update), DELETE /videos/ID (destroy).