# Where do I find the url that the built in rails server provides to store data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I want to use the `$.ajax()` call and I'm not sure where to point the `url:`

I use the embedly API to change a link to an embedded video, thumbnail, and title. The link is located in two partials. One of the partials is rendered by the `show` view, and the other is rendered in the `index` view. The views are in the `videos` directly of `views`. I want to POST the data that is generated dynamically from this link to the server. What url should I be pointing to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of resource are you trying to save? Without knowing more details it is hard to say. But, you have to setup the correct routes, controller, and models to handle your ajax requests.

Read some of the rails guides, specifically the [Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) guide to get going.

Comment: here's more info on my specific situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318940/how-do-you-save-a-dynamically-generated-element-to-your-database

Comment: Here's my specific case: All I accept is a video URL from the user and add that url as a link to the view. Then I use the embedly API to find that link and dynamically turn it into an embedded video, thumbnail, and title. I also want to allow the user to edit the title later, so I need to save the title that was generated dynamically in my `application.js` file to the db with ajax.

Comment: +1 Justin, I could be wrong but it sounds like you're missing some points about how Rails works (especially in regards to resources and routing). Rails isn't really built to "just store data," it's a full MVC framework. I'd read through the Getting Started guide that raidfive linked and see if that helps at all.

Comment: No you're probably right. I've read through Beginning Rails 3 and Michael Hartl's tutorial, but when it comes to combining Rails with AJAX, jQuery, and an API I start getting very mixed up.

Comment: One thing that might help is to keep in mind that Rails interactivity via Ajax is *almost* exactly the same as without--the only difference is that, instead of rendering HTML, you're spitting back some JavaScript. Models, Controllers, and Routing works exactly the same way, and Ajax is easy to add if you use the built-in Ajax methods (such as using `:remote => true` on your forms). The link in Ashish's answer will demonstrate this.

Comment: woops!!! I now realize how stupid I must have sounded. It really was a bad mixup that I was making. I edited the question so that it makes much more sense now. Maybe you guys will be able to answer it now.